# Get inserted ID from Sequel prepare

Tags: ruby, oracle, jruby, sequel

I have a prepared insert statement in Sequel (using Oracle).

```
prepared_statement = DB[:table_name].prepare(:insert, :name, :value=>:$value)
```

When I call it the row gets added just fine.

```
prepared_statement.call :value=>'Some value'
```

I have a trigger and a sequence set up so the ID will be auto generated. I would like to get back the row (or the id) I just added, but I can't see how. *I can't use `insert` because value is a CLOB and may be greater than 4000 characters.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JRuby, using the JDBC adapter you can override the insert and pass in the returning clause. The tricky part is that you don't always know what the primary key is at this level so you may have to use ROWID or request all of the columns back.

You end up with something that looks similar to this:

```
module Sequel
  module JDBC
    class Database
      def execute_insert_with_returning(conn, sql, opts = {})        
        columns = opts[:key_columns] || ["ROWID"]
        q = "{ call #{sql} returning #{columns.join(',')} into #{columns.collect {|_| '?'}.join(',')} }"
        stmt = conn.prepare_call(q)
        raise "Unable to prepare call for insert" if stmt.nil?

        begin
          columns.each_with_index do |_, index|
            stmt.registerOutParameter(index+1, JavaSQL::Types::VARCHAR)
          end
          return nil if 0 == stmt.executeQuery

          values = (1..columns.count).inject({}) do |memo, index|
            key = columns[index-1].downcase.to_sym rescue nil
            memo[key] = stmt.get_string(index) unless key.nil?
            memo
          end
          values
        ensure
          stmt.close
        end
      end # #execute_insert_with_returning

      alias execute_without_specialized_insert execute
      def execute(sql, opts={}, &block)
        if opts[:type] == :insert
          synchronize(opts[:server]) do |conn|
            execute_insert_with_returning conn, sql, opts
          end
        else
          execute_without_specialized_insert sql, opts, &block
        end
      end # #execute
    end # Database
  end # JDBC
end # Sequel
```

I've done something pretty much like this and it works pretty good. I think we had to override the Sequel::Model as well so it passes the primary key in as opts[:key_columns] but I may be remembering incorrectly.

This is a bit of a load bearing kludge that gets the job done. It would be more elegant to specialize it to the Oracle JDBC adapter and to ensure that all of the error handling code is present from the original execute statement. Given the time I'd love to get something better and give it back to the Sequel project.

Answer (score 0):

The way to get the populated sequence values is through the RETURNING clause of the INSERT 
statement, as I discuss in this response [to a similar question regarding CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116241/oracle-sequence-currval-problem-in-codeigniter/7124563#7124563).

I'm not sure whether the base version of RoR supports that syntax, but it appears to be possible to extend ActiveRecord to handle it. [Find out more](http://blog.thoughthook.com/?p=7).

Comment: I'm not using Rails or ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 0):

Sequel's Oracle adapter doesn't have native prepared statement support, so it falls back to issuing a regular query.  If you can use JRuby, the jdbc adapter has native prepared statement support, so it should just work there.  If you can't use JRuby, you'll have to work on adding native prepared statement support to the Oracle adapter.  I don't have access to an Oracle installation, so I can't test any support, but I'll be happy to provide advice if you run into problems.

Comment: I am using JRuby - should have tagged as such. The statement works fine, I just can't figure out how to get the generated index back.

Comment: Ah, my bad.  The problem is that the Sequel jruby oracle subadapter doesn't implement last_insert_id, and the shared oracle adapter only overrides the insert method, so it doesn't handle prepared statements (which use call).  It shouldn't be difficult to implement things, but there might be some boilerplate code to try to hook into the prepared statements (which extend datasets with a module and don't have their own classes).  It could probably do with a refactoring in the default prepared statements support to specifically check for a method to call in the :insert case to make this easier.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For the time being I have a work around. I got rid of the trigger & sequence and I'm using a UUID for the id column.